# Fragment title not showing on Marshmallow

Tags: android

For some reason, my fragment titles are not showing on marshmallow. I confirmed this based on the standard fragment activity created by android studio.  Any help is appreciated.  I tried to attach code but the standard code created by android studio and the text I initially had did not allow me to post.   Code is found [here](https://codeshare.io/h3Lnq)

Comment: We need some code to see your problem, at least use this


  https://codeshare.io/ website if you having issues about putting some codes here.

Comment: thank you!  i did not know that site exited. it is updated

Comment: and in my suggestion you must learn how  to put some code here. Maybe double newline sometimes and start everyline in same place . you can simply try this 2 step.